# Help calculating vector that is intersecting

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, rotations

I'm trying to solve a problem that is modeling a T shaped road intersection

There's three vectors that meet at a point, and I'm trying to pick the vector circled in orange (repersenting the intersecting road) out the three available ones. The only information given is three total directional vectors (one for each road)

**Examples:**

[example image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juyww.png)

[example image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om6E5.png)

I currently tried finding the angle using the Angle between Two Vectors Formula to try to solve the problem

$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \frac{\vec a \cdot \vec b}{| \vec a| | \vec b| }
$$
but I have issues since it only covers 180 degrees not 360 degrees.

How can I approach and solve this problem? I'm trying to solve this problem in a C# program I'm writing.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do exactly. Are you trying to find the components of the vector? But they can be interpreted from the picture, so I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @matti P no, I'm trying to find which vector out of the three vectors in the example image is the more perpendicular part of the T intersection (using the model)

Comment: @MattiP. Or another way, which angle between vectors 1,2, 1,3, and 2,3 is the greatest using the approach I tried already

Comment: Ah, okay! I didn't understand that, based on your post ...

Comment: Why is it a problem that the formula doesn't return angles larger than $180^{\circ}$? I don't think that in your model, there can even **be** angles larger than that. One could say that, since there are always two angles between two vectors (the "short way" and the "long way"), the angle between two vectors is always at most $180^{\circ}$ ... Do you agree? As an example, the angle between the vectors with coordinates $(4,5)$ and $(1,-5)$ is approximately $130^{\circ}$. I think that's a satisfactory result.

Comment: For example 1 it works, but in this scenario [image](https://i.imgur.com/TEXnwZG.png) I don't think it would work, the solution wouldn't be clear (it would pick the red arc) unless a rotation direction can be defined somehow by the more perpendicular part

Comment: I don't understand, why is the brown-coloured angle not accepted (but the green is)? If you're just finding angles between vectors, can't you just choose the smaller of the two possible angles?